# I could not install google client library (python) without app engine

Tags: python, pip, ubuntu-14.04, google-drive-api

I am trying to install a Google Client library:

https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-python It showing an error as follows

```
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_pcakhilnadh/google-api-python-client/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-ONyAPN-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_pcakhilnadh/google-api-python-client
Storing debug log for failure in /home/pcakhilnadh/.pip/pip.log
```

I am using an Ubuntu machine. What should I do?